# Which methods are called when user presses home button and double presses it again to return

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, multitasking

I want to know which methods (events) are called when user presses home button and double presses it again to return to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

These all called in the app delegate

All details can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html