# how to restart a application without going to recent worked page ,when we exit in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I had installed my app on ipad(ios 4) , and i was navigating through the pages of my app.whenever i close the app and re open the app it goes back to the recent page which i was working on. 
But i want it to restart the app from first page,whenever i exit and reopen .As it is working on iphone(ios 3.1.3),Can any one suggest how to do that on ipad.

thanks in advance

Comment: see this it explains good http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/screw-multi-tasking-how-to-make-your-ios-4-apps-exit-for-real/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that easily. You need to set info.plist key "Application does not run in background" to YES and it will no longer to run in background.
[image: See Image below]

Comment: This is a nice answer. I should delete mine. +1

Comment: Thanks @Praveen S. This is the easiest and proper way to achieve that according to me.

Comment: Also, You need to set boolean To **YES**. In screenshot it says to NO.

Answer (score 0):

When application enters background the delegate method `appDidEnterBackground` is called and when resumed the method `willEnterForeGround` will be called.

You can handle your application behaviour in these methods.

For more info you can refer to [this link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) which explains the concepts beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 4 the app does not exit it goes to background. And when you tap on the icon the app resumes from where you left it.

If you want to reset something when it goes in background you need to implement custom code in appDelegate methods:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to yes in your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

[Which methods are called when user presses home button and double presses it again to return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445792/which-methods-are-called-when-user-click-home-button-and-double-click-it-again-to)

here you can find answer to event on clicking on home button
interesting article

Answer (score 0):

Find your info.plist file in resources and add the key:
"Application does not run in background" and set the value to 1.